# Trying to configure a private Axios instance for use within Redux slice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-redux

So I am working on authentication for my app, and what I am trying to accomplish is providing my redux thunk functions with a private Axios instance so they can make authenticated requests. The main issue i'm having is, I want to provide the access token (which exists in the application state) to the Axios instance configuration, but this doesn't work as it requires hooks, which are not allowed in the Redux slice. I tried to access the state directly using `store.getState()`, but the store is returning `undefined`, and I also believe it won't update without the use of hooks. I am trying to produce a solution but i've come up empty. Naturally, I want to avoid using local storage for many reasons. Please don't suggest RTK-Query either. I have provided some code below:

privateInstance.ts

```
export const privateInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    withCredentials: true
});

const refresh = useRefreshToken();

const accessToken = store?.getState().auth.userContext.accessToken;

// Request interceptor for API calls
privateInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
        if (!config.headers['Authorization']) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
            config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
            config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        Promise.reject(error)
    });

// Response interceptor for API calls
privateInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response
}, async function (error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    console.log(error)
    if (error.response.status === 403 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const access_token = await refresh();
        privateInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
        return privateInstance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

useRefreshToken.ts (`instance` is just a standard Axios instance with a base url configured`)

```
const useRefreshToken = () => {
    const refresh = async () => {
        try {
            await instance({
                url: '/auth/refresh',
                method: 'GET'
            }).then((res) => {
                return res.data.accessToken
            })
        } catch (e: any) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    return refresh;
}

export default useRefreshToken;
```

exampleSlice.ts

```
...
export const addToToDoListAsync = createAsyncThunk(
    "todoList/addToToDoListAsync",
    async (todoObject: ToDoObject) => {
        try {
            return privateInstance({
                url: '/todoList',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(todoObject)
            }).then((res) => {
                return res.data;
            })
        } catch (e: any) {
            console.log(e.response.data.error)
            return e;
        }

    }
)
...
```

Request fails with a 403 forbidden as no access token is provided with this current implementation. Any help/ideas besides local storage and RTK-Query will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's rather unclear what part of using Axios or Redux requires you to use a React hook as these are both React-independent libraries. Also, so long as you have correctly created a Redux `store` object there's not any reason at all for it to be undefined or to return undefined state, e.g. `store.getState()` always returns the current state value. What is the real issue you are trying to resolve here, getting the axios instance request interceptors to read the access token from state so the refresh endpoint can be called if necessary?

Comment: My issue was that this was my first time trying to complete auth for an application, and pretty much every implementation I read didn't take this approach, so I was struggling. However, what you have mentioned is true. I called `store.getState()` directly in the request interceptor and that resolved the `undefined` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue without using hooks or RTK-Query, you can pass the access token as an argument to your thunk action creator. This way, you can access the access token from your Redux state within your component, and then pass it as an argument when dispatching the thunk action.

Here's how you can modify your addToToDoListAsync thunk action creator to accept the access token as an argument:

javascript

```
export const addToToDoListAsync = createAsyncThunk(
    "todoList/addToToDoListAsync",
    async (payload: { todoObject: ToDoObject, accessToken: string }) => {
        const { todoObject, accessToken } = payload;
        try {
            return privateInstance({
                url: '/todoList',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(todoObject)
            }).then((res) => {
                return res.data;
            })
        } catch (e: any) {
            console.log(e.response.data.error)
            return e;
        }

    }
)
```

Then, when dispatching the addToToDoListAsync action in your component, you can pass the access token as an argument:

```
import { addToToDoListAsync } from './exampleSlice';

// Assuming you have access to the access token in your component's props or state
const accessToken = 'your-access-token';

dispatch(addToToDoListAsync({ todoObject: yourTodoObject, accessToken }));
```

This way, you can access the access token from your Redux state within your component and pass it to the thunk action creator, allowing your private Axios instance to make authenticated requests without relying on hooks or RTK-Query.

Comment: I do quite like this solution, and I think with usage of `thunkApi` it could make it better. Thanks.